# Why did sns.scatterplot produce a different output compared to plt.scatter on the same dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, pca

I tried to visualise the PCA transformed data of the MNIST Digit dataset using `sns.scatterplot` and plt.scatter approaches as below

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

dim_1 = X_train.shape[0]
dim_2 = X_train.shape[1]
dim_3 = X_train.shape[2]

arr = X_train.reshape(dim_1, dim_2 * dim_3)
sc = StandardScaler()
norm_arr = sc.fit_transform(arr)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_arr = pca.fit_transform(norm_arr)
pca_arr = np.vstack((pca_arr.T, y_train)).T
pca_df = pd.DataFrame(data=pca_arr, columns=("1st_principal", "2nd_principal", "label"))
pca_df = pca_df.astype({'label': 'int32'})
```

Using scatterplot from matplotlib produces this visual:

```
sns.FacetGrid(pca_df, hue="label", height=6).map(plt.scatter, '1st_principal', '2nd_principal').add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

On the other hand, scatterplot from seaborn is quite different, in particular the locations of digits 9 (on the bottom right hand corner instead of upper left hand corner compared to the first plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
sns.scatterplot(x = pca_arr_combo[:, 0], y = pca_arr_combo[:, 1], 
                hue = pca_arr_combo[:, 2], palette = sns.hls_palette(10), legend = 'full')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can someone please explain why 2 different visuals can be produced on the same dataset? I was wondering `sns.FacetGrid` had something to do with it, but not sure why? Which scatterplot was correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You are plotting many dots on almost the same positions, and seaborn plots them in a different order than standard matplotlib.  You might consider choosing smaller dots, and/or transparency to better visualize your data.  Your first example plots the hue values one by one, leaving `9` at the top.  Your second example plots the rows of the dataframe in order, which probably is more randomized and thus better visualizes what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC. The colours of the digits threw me off, confusing between digits `0` and `9`.

Comment: The `hsl` palette has its first and last color equal, making it a confusing choice to show 10 
independent categories.  Maybe `palette='bright'` works better in your case? Or a subset of 'hls', e.g. `palette=sns.hls_palette(15)[10]`?

Comment: You might try `sns.kdeplot(x=pca_arr_combo[:,0], y=pca_arr_combo[:,1], hue=pca_arr_combo[:,2])` for a visualization that shows where each digit is concentrated.

Comment: Thank you, @JohanC. You gave me more tips than what my OP was about.